# NodeJS crypto for encrypt/decrypt

Tags: node.js, encryption

I'm working on a database with some encrypted data that was generated in ColdFusion using the code below:

```
key = "nQw7y6QejwGFh/SNrul20Q==";
encrypt(myText, key, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "HEX");
```

It generates an encrypted string like: `6F795025756EC54D60808EA98AC163D9143C2FCFEC1065FCCAB7AB0CD577E535`. I can decrypt it using my code below

I managed to create my NodeJS class to decrypt this data.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const key = Buffer.from('nQw7y6QejwGFh/SNrul20Q==', 'base64');  

module.exports = class Encrypt {

    decryptText(text) {
        try {
            const ivCiphertext = Buffer.from(text, 'hex');
            const iv = ivCiphertext.slice(0, 16);
            const ciphertext = ivCiphertext.slice(16);
            var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('AES-128-CBC', key, iv);
            var value = 
                decipher.update(ciphertext, '', 'utf8') +
                decipher.final('utf8');
            return value;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
};
```

I'm trying to create a encrypt method in this class, to encrypt the data in the same format that it was being generated in ColdFusion.

```
   encrypt(text) {
        const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
        let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv( 
            'AES-128-CBC', key, iv);
        let encrypted = cipher.update(text);
        encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]); 
        return encrypted.toString('hex');
    }
```

I did the following test:

```
const encrypt = new Encrypt();
const test = encrypt.encrypt('803315808');
console.log(test);
console.log(encrypt.decryptText(test));
```

First log:

```
fdcec1c7098c0fc91a11ada1e849b543
```

Second log:

```
Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
```

Comment: In `encrypt()` you must also concatenate the IV: `encrypted = Buffer.concat([iv, encrypted, cipher.final()]);`

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you. If you want to add it as an answer, I can accept as correct answer